# Command line in vi mode: replace all

Tags: bash, vi

How do I replace globally from the command line in vi mode. It seems like I can't use ex commands by prefixing with `:`, so what do I do instead.

for instance if I want to replace all `\` with `/` in a command...

Comment: Just a second... when you say from the command line, do you mean from the shell? Glenn Jackman has been downvoted, but maybe his answer is what you are looking for -- except for the backslashes?

Comment: You can edit commands in the bash history using an external editor using the `fc` built-in (see `help fc`).  emacs mode also has a ^X^E binding for `edit-and-execute-command-line`, while the binding in vi mode is `Esc v`.  see http://superuser.com/questions/736368/im-using-bash-in-vi-mode-whats-the-hotkey-sequence-to-edit-the-current-comm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use the [bash history mechanism](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction):

```
$ echo 'foo\bar\baz'
foo\bar\baz
$ !!:gs/b/B/
echo 'foo\Bar\Baz'
foo\Bar\Baz
```

However, I can't seem to get it to replace backslashes

```
$ echo 'foo\bar\baz'
foo\bar\baz
$ !!:gs/\\/\//
bash: :gs/\\/\//: substitution failed
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems replacing \ with / globally inside vi, it's because the first character is special and needs to be escaped, and the second is usually chosen as sed separator and so also needs to be escaped. You can use:

```
:%!tr '\\' '/'
```

or

```
:%s,\\,/,g
```

or

```
:%s/\\/\//g
```

For completeness, this is what you would have to do if you're using plain vi (without macros) and you do not want to use ex-mode:

```
/\\
r/nr/nr/nr/nr/nr/nr/nr/nr/nr/nr/n
```

repeat that last for as many times needed, I only include it to show what you must do if you do not want to use ex-mode.

Answer (score 1):

on the vi command mode

```
:1,$s+\\+/+g
```

this replaces all backslash characters with forward slashes`

Comment: No need for 1,$.  Replace with %

Answer (score 1):

`vi` provides more than one way to do this.  To address *all* lines in `ex` (the ":" lines), you can use either `%` or `1,$`.  Likewise, it allows different *delimiters* for the `s` (substitute command).  So you could have these variations:

```
:%s/\\/\//g
:%s,\\,/,g
:1,$s/\\/\//g
:1,$s,\\,/,g
```

the point being that

- backslash is a *meta* character for the regular expressions used in substitution, and has to be *escaped* to use it,
- the delimiter has to be a punctuation character, and
- finally, (in the first and third examples), it is possible to use the *delimiter* as part of the before/after strings, but in that case it also has to be escaped.

Comment: I was going to say that the delimiter does not have to be a punctuation character, but apparently in vi's internal sed-like command it does. It cannot be `|`, though. In normal `sed` anything goes.

Comment: But `ex` is not `sed` (they're similar).  Usually I just use `/` and am used to escaping it...

Comment: And vi actually *is* ex, yes :) In any case I think we're very far from answering the actual question which seems to be bash command line in vi mode.